# One System Tray (Notification Area) Icon disappears after logon

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, notification-area

I have a specific icon that will show in the notification area for only about 5 seconds after logging onto the computer then it disappears.  When I look in task manager I can see the application is running and if I end Explorer then restart it then the icon re-appears.

Any ideas what would cause this?

I've already tried to deleted the IconStreams from the registry and that had no effect on this.

This particular machine i'm working on is Windows 10, but I have also seen it happen using the same software on a Windows 7 machine.

I am the administrator of this computer.

The app in question is called Imprivata.  It's a single sign on application and the icon should be permanently in the notification area until exited.

Comment: If it happens on two different PCs with different OS, and you're the admin, the software is either faulty or designed not to show the icon in the Tray. Please consult the software publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being a application conflict between Imprivata and Informacast Desktop Notifier.  Imprivata would load first and then when Informacast Desktop Notifier would load the icon for Imprivata would disappear.  I ended up creating a startup delay so that Informacast Desktop Notifier starts before Imprivata and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to reinstall the Imprivata. If it doesn’t work, create a new account and use this new account to install this APP. 
create a new user account:

1. Open User Accounts by opening Control Panel, and then clicking User
   Accounts.
2. Click Manage another account and Click Add a new account.
3. Type the name you want to give the user account, and then click
       Create.
4. Sign out from the current account and log on the new
       account.

If this issue disappear, try to fix the user profile.

Copy files to the new user profiles: After you create the profile, you can copy the files from the existing profile. You must have at least three user accounts on the computer to complete these steps, including the new account you just created.

1. Log on as a user other than the new user you just created or the
   user that you want to copy files from.
2. Open Computer. Double-click the hard disk drive that Windows is
   installed on (it's usually your C: drive), double-click Users,
   double-click the folder with the name of your account, and then
   double-click My Documents.
3. Click the view menu, and then click Options.
4. Click the View tab, and then click Show hidden files, folders, and
   drives.
5. Clear the Hide protected operating system files check box, click Yes
   to confirm, and then click OK.
6. Locate the C:\Users\Old_Username folder, where C is the drive that
   Windows is installed on, and Old_Username is the name of the profile
   you want to copy files from.
7. Select all of the files and folders in this folder, except the
   following files:
   Ntuser.dat 
   Ntuser.dat.log
   Ntuser.ini
8. Right click and click Copy.
9. Locate the C:\Users\New_Username folder, where C is the drive that
   Windows is installed on, and New_Username is the name of the new
   user profile you created.
10. Right click and click Paste.
11. Log off the current account, and then log into the new user.